# Get filename from dired using elisp

Tags: dired, files

Using elisp, I call this function `(dired "~")`, for example, to get to my Home directory in dired mode. When I press `RET` on one of the files, I want to capture the file path and store it in a variable instead of opening the file.

In other words, if the function `dired` did actually return the file name of the selected file using `RET`, I want to do something like this:

`(setq file-name (dired "~"))`

Where `file-name` would be the full path of the file that the user selected and pressed `RET` on.

Any ideas?

---

**Update**:

Just a little clarification of what I wanted to achieve:

1. Find the function that will get me the file name from `point` in a Dired buffer (The answer to that is what @phils said).
2. Bind `RET` to store the file name in a variable (The answer to that was provided by @Drew in the comments of @phils answer).

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine the function `dired-get-filename` is what you're looking for?

Or perhaps `dired-get-file-for-visit` would be more useful (being a wrapper which handles some common errors).

Comment: Thanks @phills for the quick reply, I've tried something like this:

`(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (dired "~")
  (setq x (dired-get-filename)))`

and it seems to work, the variable `x` does capture the selected filename. However, there's one problem, I have to open the file by pressing `RET` to get the filename. Is there a way to prevent dired from opening the selected file when pressing `RET`? I might be using the `dired-get-filename` function in a wrong way, so maybe you could provide a little code snippet? :D

Thanks again.

Comment: Based on your comment it is not clear what you are really trying to do. @phils's answer tells you how to set a variable's value to the name of the file at point. Now you are talking about having to press `RET` to open the file and asking how to not open the file by pressing `RET` (?). Why are you hitting `RET`? Please consider clarifying your original question a bit.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to change the key binding of `RET` in Dired to a command that just puts the file name at point into a variable?

Comment: Hello @Drew, yes, your last comment is what I want to achieve. When I hit `RET` I want the file at point to be stored in a variable. Shall I modify the original question?

Comment: Yes, please. The answer then is probably to drop the `(dired "~")` from your command `test` and bind `test` to `RET` in `dired-mode-map`: `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'test)`. Once a user is in a Dired buffer, `RET` will then copy the file name to variable `x`. Not sure that is a great idea, though.

Comment: BTW, are you aware that `w` in Dired copies the file name to the `kill-ring`, so you can yank it? Dunno whether that helps your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Drew, yeah I'm aware of `w` in Dired. I think you are probably right, I might be using Dired for something it's not meant to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post but I was recently looking for something similar and stumbled upon this. My goal was: "use `dired` to retrieve a file's name". As mentioned in this post's Accepted Answer's comments, `dired` doesn't seem to be made for this.

I'm new to `elisp` so there might be plenty of better ways than my approach demonstrates, but I hope that it is helpful for anyone trying to do something similar.

My solution was to use `completing-read` and `directory-files` to get something close to this behaviour:

```
  (defun find-in-directory (path)
    "Find file in directory."
    (interactive)
    (let ((filename
           (completing-read "File: " (directory-files-recursively path "\\.txt$"))))
      filename))
```

`completing-read` provides the auto-complete functionality using `directory-files` (here, `directory-files-recursively`) as the source (i.e., what can be selected or auto-completed on). I've also included a `"\\.txt$"` argument to limit the extensions of the returned files, demonstratively, though it isn't neccessary per OP's use-case.

Comment: One could always use functions like `mapcar` to transform the file names for the auto-complete (e.g., to remove the directory portion of the string) - just be sure that however it is returned is the format that is required.

Comment: Why not use `read-file-name`?

Comment: @Stefan Fair point! `read-file-name` will do auto-complete on files in the current directory, but none of the nested files; it isn't recursive. If you're looking for nested files, you'll have to navigate. For my use-case, I wanted to auto-complete on the file names without having to navigate folders. So, "user experience", let's say. :)